# How to combine BrowserNavConstants in c++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, webbrowser-control

I am trying to use BrowserNavConstants for .Navigate2 flags, but I dont know how to combine more than one in the same variant for c++. On VB i would use

```
navNoHistory + navNoReadFromCache + navNoWriteToCache
```

or

```
Flags := NavNoHistory or NavNoReadFromCache or NavNoWriteToCache or NavAllowAutosearch;
```

for delphi, but how should I do it on c++?

Answer (score 0):

Normally you'd combine flags with the bitwise OR operator ('|') for C++; does this not work here?

Eg:

```
Flag = Value1 | Value2 | Value3;
```

Comment: But how do i create a variant with type VT_I4 or VT_I2 and assign that in c++?

Comment: This compiles fine, V_VT(&vFlags) = VT_I4;
    V_I4(&vFlags) = navNoHistory | navNoReadFromCache